# Can a distance function be derived from a displacement function?

Tags: kinematics, distance, displacement

If I have some function $\vec{x}(t)$ that represents the displacement function for some object $x$, is it possible to derive a distance function $d(t)$ for that same object, representing the total scalar distance that the object has travelled?

I am aware that it can be done in specific cases, when the motion of $x$ is restricted to one dimension, it is just $d = \int_a^b|v(t)| ~ dt$ which requires splitting the function into cases by finding where the sign of $v(t)$ changes.

But is there a general method to calculate the distance function in the general case, where $\vec{x}(t)$ is the displacement function for an object in any $n$-dimensional system?

Comment: Can you not do $\vec v=d \vec x/dt$ and then use your formula?

Comment: The above comment is correct, and this result's derivation is the same as for the single-dimensional case.